# Model with a has_one relationship with a i18n-able attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application, I have a model called `event.rb` and I want to each event to have a `type`. I don't want to add a column in the db for the attribute type because there will be like 10 different types (and not much more than that) and I want it to be i18n, that the same value have a string representation in english, portuguese, spanish, and so one and so forth.

Any ideas?

Comment: i would suggest to create a new model `EventType` add `one to many` association between `event` and `EventType` and in `EventType` has all representation of strings in it and you can access them through `Event.last.event_types` and that will return you all the types for that event.

Comment: it's a start, and how do I make it i18n?

Comment: for that i guess you need to use some gem. i18n or rails-18n. https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n. but still things depend on your requirement. if your types are constant. populate types in all language using seed.rb and add many to many relation between type and event through event types.

Answer (score 0):

Since these types are constants, you could create a module containing all different types, and define each one in your i18n files. So, you can search for the translated text by something like `event.type` wherever you want.